# Which distribution to use

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem

> After many generations, it is known that **75%** of students pass certain subject. if a **random sample of 40** students is such that it could be consider they have the same characteristics as the ones observed. ¿Which is the probability that **at least 50%** of them pass the subject?

I would say that $X\sim Bernoulli(.75)$, also I would like to use Central Limit Theorem or any other distribution to approximate the probability of the 40 student sample. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. You could model each student's success as a Bernoulli random variable with $p = 0.75$ probability of success.

Also, embedding the CLT here sounds like a good approximation because it seems exhaustive to compute the following probability
$$Pr( \sum_{i=1}^{40} X_i \geq 20)$$
where $X_i \sim B(0.75)$. Equivalently, we can say (dividing $40$ on both sides)
$$Pr( S_{40} \geq 0.5)$$ where 
$$S_{40} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{40} X_i}{40}$$
The CLT tells you that if $X_1 \ldots X_{40}$ are i.i.d (which is your case), then
$$\sqrt{40}(S_{40} - \mu) \rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$$
where 
\begin{align}
\mu &= E(X) = p = 0.75 \\
\sigma^2 &= \operatorname{var}(X) = p(1-p) = 0.75(0.25) = \frac{3}{8} \\
\end{align}
Hence, we get
$$\sqrt{40}(S_{40} - 0.75) \rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0,\frac{3}{8})$$
You could choose to standardize as such
$$Z = \frac{S_{40} - 0.75}{\frac{\frac{3}{8}}{\sqrt{40}}} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$
Going back to your probability
$$Pr( S_{40} \geq 0.5)$$
All you have to do is standardize now, i.e.
$$
Pr(\frac{S_{40} - 0.75}{\frac{\frac{3}{8}}{\sqrt{40}}}\geq \frac{20 - 0.75}{\frac{\frac{3}{8}}{\sqrt{40}}}) = Pr (Z \geq \frac{20 - 0.75}{\frac{\frac{3}{8}}{\sqrt{40}}})$$
and this is the **Normal Approximation of the Binomial Distribution.**